# StringLengthValidator - localization not working

Tags: asp.net, enterprise-library

I am validating input to my ASP.NET application using StringLengthValidators, and using the ValidationSummary control to display the error messages.  To localize the application, the StringLengthValidators have the MessageTemplateResourceName and MessageTemplateResourceType attributes set.

The first time the validator runs, it picks up the correct error message based on the current culture setting.  If I change the language setting while running the app, the next time the validator runs, the ValidationSummary it still displays the error message for the old culture.  The text for all other controls is being updated correctly.

Any ideas, folks?